# How to retrieve token from acs using client certificate?

Tags: wcf, saml, servicebus, acs

I want to use ACS as a STS for the service bus. I've managed to use ACS for authentication for a web service. However, the service bus requires a token and I don't know how to retrieve such from the ACS?

In short, I want my client wcf services to be able to use the service bus by authenticating with certificates that matches certificates stored as service identities in the acs (the one corresponding to the service bus -sb).

Also, I'm using NetTcpRelayBinding for the Service Bus.

I guess I can use a token from acs if I can just retrieve it using the client certificate...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a token from ACS using client certificate credentials over WCF is a well supported scenario.

There is an ACS sample that does WCF client certificate auth available [here](http://acs.codeplex.com/releases/view/57595), look for Acs2CertificateBindingSample. Points of interest are how to create the binding that obtains a token from ACS:

```
    public static Binding CreateServiceBinding(string acsCertificateEndpoint)
    {
        return new IssuedTokenWSTrustBinding(CreateAcsCertificateBinding(), new EndpointAddress(acsCertificateEndpoint));
    }

    public static Binding CreateAcsCertificateBinding()
    {
        return new CertificateWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
    }
```

And how to create the channel factory using this binding, and how to specify your client certificate credential:

```
ChannelFactory<IStringService> stringServiceFactory = new ChannelFactory<IStringService>(Bindings.CreateServiceBinding(acsCertificateEndpoint), serviceEndpointAddress);

// Set the service credentials and disable certificate validation to work with sample certificates
stringServiceFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
stringServiceFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = GetServiceCertificate();

// Set the client credentials.
stringServiceFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = GetClientCertificateWithPrivateKey();
```

The sample is not using service bus, just a simple "IStringService" interface, but if you incorporateyour NetTcpRelayBinding into the binding composition, the same mechanisms should be applicable to your scenario.